# How much pygame is strong (for doing big games...)

Tags: pygame

I just tried to learn pygame, and its really fun module to learn.

But, i wondered how strong is this module?

Can i (just for example) create "warcraft 2" game with it and pygame will hold  the all graphic and things like that?
If not, so what languages is strong enough to do a strategy games with?
And - what is the power of pygame.
Is there any limitations?

I understand from friends that cpp is my answer. 
But i want to hear it from you and with a bit more information.

Comment: pygame uses SDL, which you can use with cpp. I would suggest you try it, and if you find limitations switch to C++ or SFML/Python. the language may not be an issue unless you want to port it on a not-so-powerful device.

Comment: jean, by your answer should i realize that is posibble to do with pygame games like warcraft2\Age of Empires etc...?

Comment: it's not an answer but a comment. SDL handles 2D graphics very well. If you want to go 3D, I'm not sure at all... and performance will be an issue. BTW Minecraft is written in Java.

Answer (score 2):

It is a little hard to tell from your questions wording, but I believe you're asking: *'Can Pygame be used to create high level 3d graphics games?'*

If that is your question, then **no**, it cannot. Pygame is not designed to be used to make high level 3d graphical games. Pygame is however, built upon the SDL library, which **can** support creating 3d graphical games.

Also there is no 'cpp' game creating module, so assume you mean [C++](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4). You friends are right though, C++ is really the best language to go with if trying to make a graphics intensive game. But before you go off trying to create a game from scratch in C++, with the graphics library of your choice, why not use a already engine game engine such as [Unreal](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4) or [Unity](https://unity3d.com/). You'd make your game much quicker than you ever would starting from scratch.

Comment: mmm... ok, i get you. and in 2d big games, pygame is ok? and when i say big i mean real big.

Comment: Well I'd say that Pygame is pretty good for that sort of task.